# Android build issue in Cordova 8.0

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-8.0.0

I was using cordova 7.0.0 for creating my android project now i need to update it to Cordova 8.0.0. I have installed the cordova 8.0.0 version then removed and add the android platform v8.0.0 to my project. 
When i give the command cordova clean it gives a success. But on giving the build command cordova build android. It is giving the following error,

config file undefined requested for changes not found at D:\Project-Path\pla
tforms\android\undefined, ignoring
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\Project-Path\hooks\a
fter_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js" "D:\Project-Path"

It seems that a configuration file is missing. Not able to find out which one.

If anyone have faced this situation please suggest a solution. I am stuck with this for a day.

Attaching the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the exact errors thrown? also, use Cordova build with --stacktrace which will give you more detailed errors

Comment: I have tried it with --stacktrace but it doesnot give any more details. I am attaching the screenshot

Comment: any solution to this?